# Insert data from IOT 2040 to MYSQL (AWS EC2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, node-red, bitnami

[image: Node-red Image]

I am working in IoT 2040 with energy meters. I took data from Energy meter but I want to insert these data in AWS EC2 Phpmyadmin MYSQL in bitnami. I tried

```
1. (npm install node-red-node-mysql these commands install mysql in node-red
2. Added Inbound rule for MYSQL 
3. Changed my MSQL into remote access [link][2]
```

I tried these things but MYSQL(AWS EC2 bitnami) is not connected shown error mysql database error connect EHOSTUNREACH help me to solve this problem

Comment: That error means that the machine you are running node red can not reach the machine running msql (assuming you entered the right address). Are you sure you've not used the internal private IP address or that you have opened the correct ports?

Comment: Thanks for the response @hardillb Above method is ok or any another method can you give me suggestion.